# How to instantly clear Kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using the below command to clear messages in the topic. But this does not delete all messages instantly and I can still see messages.

```
kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name topic1 --add-config retention.ms=1000,cleanup.policy=delete
```

After running this cmd and waiting for few minutes, I delete the config.

```
kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name topic1 --delete-config retention.ms,cleanup.policy
```

What is the correct set of parameters to be used to instantly remove all messages from the topic?

Comment: The correct way is not having to delete messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour. The approach that you are following to delete the messages in a Kafka Topic is correct, but it takes some time to get rid of all the messages, especially for fairly large topics. There's nothing you can do about it.

You can also try to manually delete the messages and see if it is any faster (although this method is not recommended, especially for production environments):

1. Shutdown your Kafka Cluster
2. Clear the content of your Kafka log directory (i.e. the directory defined by `log.dirs` in `server.properties` file) as well as the corresponding Zookeeper data
3. Restart your Kafka Cluster

Comment: How do we know about the amount of time its gonna take to clean up ?

Comment: @Tony Unfortunately, we don't.